# Unable to apply string formatting in Silverlight DataGrid column

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, datagrid, format

I have a Data Grid. Its Item source is set to a List. My  problem is that Iam unable to apply string formatting .  This is formats Ive tried . Am I missing some thing ?
StringFormat='MM/dd/yyyy'
StringFormat={0:dd-MMM-yyyy}

Attached the resultant grid

```
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn   Header="Recieved Date" Width="Auto"  >
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RecievedDate, StringFormat=\{0:dd-MMM-yyyy\} }" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <sdk:DatePicker Name="dtpFinancialAndComplianceLog" Text="{Binding Path=RecievedDate,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, you have a DataGrid column which you want to display a DateTime object in a certain format.  Ordinarily a DateTime object will sort out its own formatting depending on the System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture.

Easiest way I know of to force any object into a certain format is to use a custom IValueConverter:

```
namespace MyProject.Converters
{
    public class FormatConverter : IValueConverter
    {//Suitable only for read-only data

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
                return string.Empty;
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.ToString()))
                return value.ToString();

            return string.Format(culture, parameter.ToString(), value);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

After adding a namespace to your xaml: `xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:MyProject.Converters"` and declaring your converter in the control's resources `<conv:FormatConverter x:Key="Formatter" />`, you will need to bind your column's data using your new converter:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=RecievedDate, Converter={StaticResource Formatter}, ConverterParameter=\{0:dd-MMM-yyy\} }" />
```